# Unique scientific software getting 0xc00007b error after update on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, qt

The program is a custom developed user interface and calculation tool built-in c++ and QT, it uses unfortunately a lot of different components, And I can't tell what's failing because of the nondescriptness of the error code.

Program compiles just fine and was working perfectly well before the update, unfortunately, this is a project I've been working on for quite a while and is quite large.

Thank you

Sorry for such an inane question

EDIT:
as for running it with a debugger, it does not get to that point, the program starts to launch, then dies with that error message, thank you

Edit:
code was 100% fine before the update, so was looking for advice, sorry

Comment: Have you tried running the program through a debugger and looking at the stack trace?

Comment: You can create a [mcve] and post it here into your question. A debugger will help you find the component that causes the problem. If you are looking for someone to debug your whole project you should consider hiring a paid freelancer.

Comment: it does not get to the point where I can step through, dies instantly

Comment: That error matches  `ERROR_INVALID_NAME` in `winerror.h`. `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`. You should start `procmon`, then start your app and look what file(s) it's searching for (and not finding).

Comment: Thank you! I would say that is the answer if you post it as an answer as I was looking for a place to start!

Answer (score 3):

Looks like [`STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55) to me. So it failed trying to load the *.exe file or some *.dll dependency.

To figure out which binary it had trouble loading you can use [Gflags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/gflags) to enable [loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps) for your *.exe file.

Then when you start your exe file from within a debugger like WinDbg it should output the loader debugging info.

Comment: `0x000007B` is STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT but `0x00007B` is ERROR_INVALID_NAME. The image format error does make more sense though, perhaps OP mistyped.